# What is the standard term for the property of an order-embedding $h \colon P \to P$ such that for all $a \in P$, $a \leq h(a)$?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

In an essay, I want to talk about order-embeddings $h \colon P \to P$ on a partially ordered set P such that

for all $a \in P$, $a \leq h(a)$.

Does somebody know the standard term for a function with that property? And also the converse ($h(a) \leq a$)? Help with maybe a reference or two would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: In the special case of set theory where sets are ordered by inclusion, I believe functions like these are called _progressing functions_.

Comment: According to the wikipedia page on closure operators, a map satisfying this property would be called extensive.

Comment: Thank you for you help (@ZeroXLR, @Eran)! As I'm not really dealing with set theory and also not with operators on set (such a closure operators), neither "progressing function" nor "extensive" is a very suitable term. By following up the literature on the term "extensive", I have found the term "inflationary" used several times for functions on more general posets. So, I think I will use this one. Thanks anyways, without your lead, I would not have found it!